# NASM ways to create symbols local to a function and how they behave in case of recursion

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, nasm, local-variables

From what I have learned, I could very well be wrong, to have local variables for a function in NASM we can either:

- Use an offset with the function's base pointer and space on the stack to act as local variables.
- Declare symbols after the function label in an additional section .data or .bss as shown below.

  ```
  section .text
  _FindLongestString:

  section .data
   .length dd 0
   .address dd 0

   push ebp
   mov  ebp, esp

   ; more instructions

   mov  esp, ebp
   pop ebp
  ```

If we use the second method can it be recursive? Or would each iteration of the function be accessing the same memory space when they reference a local symbol like `.length`?

I imagine the first method would not have a problem with recursion since each iteration would reserve space on the stack for its own variables.

Comment: Your example is missing a `section .text` directive after the variables. Other than that you can do some things using NASM preprocessor macros to help declaring local variables in a stack frame, mine are available at https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/lmacros/file/541d99bc6847/lmacros2.mac#l25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Static storage in `.data` only exists once, where you put it.**  In this case, you put your code inside `section .data` since you switched to it and didn't switch back to `section .text`.

`.length dd 0` is like C `static int length;` - all invocations of your function use the same 4 bytes of static storage.

If you want unique space for local variables in each invocation of re-entrant code (such as a recursive and/or thread-safe function), use stack space like C compilers would for `int length;`.  (Without `static`, so automatic storage-class.)

---

Switching to `.data` or `.bss` *and back* and using only `.` local labels is a way to get their names scoped to the function while reserving static storage.  This is pretty much equivalent to C `static int length;` at function scope.  I'd put the static data stuff after the function body, but that's just a style choice since each section has its own current position.

---

NASM processes the source file in source order.  Not in execution order: remember it's just an assembler not an interpreter.  Assembling a `call` or `jmp` instruction into machine code doesn't make it go back and re-assemble older lines.

Each NASM source line tells NASM to append some bytes into the current section of the object file.  This is what assembling is.  `db 0x90` is exactly identical to `nop`, for example.  NASM just knows how to encode instructions, it doesn't care how they'll execute.

Loops and recursion are a run-time thing, happening long after assembling and linking is done.

In terms of a train track or race-car analogy, the assembler builds the tracks, the CPU follows them.  (Not a perfect analogy here because it's fine for multiple threads to be executing the same function, just not to be using the same static storage unless that's intended.)